# PHP sorting table data

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a php page with a multideminsional array. The array needs to be put into an html table and be able to be sorted based on any of four columns. Two of the columns are alphabetical and two are numeric.

Here's my array code.

```
$poptable=array(
    array('State' => 'Alabama',
    'Capital' => 'Montgomery',
    'pop2010' => 4779736,
    'poprank' => 23),

    array('State' => 'Alaska',
    'Capital' => 'Juneau',
    'pop2010' => 710231,
    'poprank' => 47),

    array('State' => 'Arizona',
    'Capital' => 'Phoenix',
    'pop2010' => 6329017,
    'poprank' => 18),

    array('State' => 'Arkansas',
    'Capital' => 'Little Rock',
    'pop2010' => 2915918,
    'poprank' => 32),

    array('State' => 'California',
    'Capital' => 'Sacramento',
    'pop2010' => 37253956,
    'poprank' => 1),

    array('State' => 'Colorado',
    'Capital' => 'Denver',
    'pop2010' => 5029196,
    'poprank' => 22),

    array('State' => 'Connecticut',
    'Capital' => 'Hartford',
    'pop2010' => 3518288,
    'poprank' => 29),

    array('State' => 'Delaware',
    'Capital' => 'Dover',
    'pop2010' => 897934,
    'poprank' => 45),

    array('State' => 'Florida',
    'Capital' => 'Tallahassee',
    'pop2010' => 18801301,
    'poprank' => "4"),

    array('State' => 'Georgia',
    'Capital' => 'Atlanta',
    'pop2010' => 9687653,
    'poprank' => 9),

    array('State' => 'Hawaii',
    'Capital' => 'Boise',
    'pop2010' => 1360301,
    'poprank' => 42));
```

I need to read the data into an HTML table. Then the user needs to be able to click on links that will be in the table header that will be able to sort each column ascending or descending depending on what they want.

EDIT:

Here is my array and my code to read array into table.

```
<?php

$poptable=array(
    array('State' => 'Alabama',
    'Capital' => 'Montgomery',
    'pop2010' => 4779736,
    'poprank' => 23),

    array('State' => 'Alaska',
    'Capital' => 'Juneau',
    'pop2010' => 710231,
    'poprank' => 47),

    array('State' => 'Arizona',
    'Capital' => 'Phoenix',
    'pop2010' => 6329017,
    'poprank' => 18),

    array('State' => 'Arkansas',
    'Capital' => 'Little Rock',
    'pop2010' => 2915918,
    'poprank' => 32),

    array('State' => 'California',
    'Capital' => 'Sacramento',
    'pop2010' => 37253956,
    'poprank' => 1),

    array('State' => 'Colorado',
    'Capital' => 'Denver',
    'pop2010' => 5029196,
    'poprank' => 22),

    array('State' => 'Connecticut',
    'Capital' => 'Hartford',
    'pop2010' => 3518288,
    'poprank' => 29),

    array('State' => 'Delaware',
    'Capital' => 'Dover',
    'pop2010' => 897934,
    'poprank' => 45),

    array('State' => 'Florida',
    'Capital' => 'Tallahassee',
    'pop2010' => 18801301,
    'poprank' => "4"),

    array('State' => 'Georgia',
    'Capital' => 'Atlanta',
    'pop2010' => 9687653,
    'poprank' => 9),

    array('State' => 'Hawaii',
    'Capital' => 'Boise',
    'pop2010' => 1360301,
    'poprank' => 42));


function array2table($array, $recursive = false, $null = '&nbsp;')
{
    if (!isset($array[0]) || !is_array($array[0]))
    {
            $array = array($array);
    }

    // Start the table
    $table = "<center><table width='35%' border='1'>\n";

    // The header
    $table .= "\t<tr>";

    // Take the keys from the first row as the headings
    foreach (array_keys($array[0]) as $heading)
            {
                    $table .= '<th>' . $heading . '</th>';
            }
    $table .= "</tr>\n";

    // The body
    foreach ($array as $row)
    {
            $table .= "\t<tr>" ;
            foreach ($row as $cell)
                    {
                    $table .= '<td>';
                    // Cast objects
                    if (is_object($cell)) { $cell = (array) $cell; }
                    if ($recursive === true && is_array($cell) && !empty($cell))
                    {
                    // Recursive mode
                    $table .= "\n" . array2table($cell, true, true) . "\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            $table .= (strlen($cell) > 0) ?
                            htmlspecialchars((string) $cell) :
                            $null;
                    }
                    $table .= '</td>';
            }
            $table .= "</tr>\n";
    }
    $table .= '</table>';
    return $table;
}
```

Comment: Take a look to Datatable plugin (https://datatables.net/), it does what you want to achieve. You will juste have to loop throught your array to build your HTML table.

Comment: I have to be able to do this in all in php.